# How to change selected text attribute into bold in TMemo in delphi 7 ?

Tags: delphi, tmemo

I use TMemo to be able to display multiple lines.

I want to change selected text attribute in TMemo into bold using the shortcut Ctrl+B.

For example, User enters "Hello, how are you?"  in the Tmemo, I want when when user selects "How" and press Ctrl+B then only "How" should be appeared in Bold in that TMemo.

I use Delphi 7.

Please advice to get solution. thanks for help.

Comment: TMemo doesn't support that out of the box and it would require a lot of work to get it to do so. You may be better off switching to a TRichEdit and learn how to work with its formatting.

Comment: Can't get `TMemo` to do it at all. Trivial with `TRichEdit`.

Comment: Any hint to make it possible using TRichEdit? thanks

Comment: I am able to set font as Bold using RichEdit. Can someone help me to set the hotkey Ctrl+B to call xyz procedure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You are probably right. I kept the possibility open because the TMS component suite has highlighting available in its memo components, and I didn't know their ancestry off the top of my head. Checked it. They are descending straight from TCustomControl...

Comment: @naren About having a Hotkey try this on `OnKeyDown` event

`if (((GetKeyState(VK_control) AND 128)=128) AND (key=Ord('B'))) then
   begin   
  //ur procedure  
  end;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't format text in a memo control. You need a rich edit control, [`TRichEdit`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TRichEdit).

In order to make the current selection bold you do this:

```
RichEdit.SelAttributes.Style := RichEdit.SelAttributes.Style + [fsBold];
```

The preferred way to invoke code in response to a shortcut like <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd> is to use actions. Add a `TActionList` to the form and add an action to that action list. Set the action's `OnExecute` event handler to point at code that performs the bolding of the selected text. Set the `Shortcut` property to `Ctrl+A`. Use actions so that you can centralise the control of user events. Typically there may also be a tool button, a menu item and a context menu item that performed the same action and this is where actions come into their own.

Answer (score 2):

Here's part of a program which I wrote which uses a RichEdit; part of the line is displayed in black, part in blue and possibly part in bold red. 'Text' is a field of the RichEdit.

```
procedure TWhatever.InsertText (const atext, btext, ctext: string);
begin
 with RichEdit1 do
  begin
   selstart:= length (text);
   sellength:= 0;
   SelAttributes.Color:= clBlack; 
   seltext:= '[' + atext + '] ';

   selstart:= length (text);
   sellength:= 0;
   SelAttributes.Color:= clBlue;
   seltext:= btext + ' ';

   if ctext <> '' then
    begin   // trap non-existent answers
     selstart:= length (text);
     sellength:= 0;
     SelAttributes.Color:= clRed;
     SelAttributes.Style:= [fsBold];
     seltext:= ctext + ' ';
     SelAttributes.Style:= [];
    end;
   lines.add ('');  // new line
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I am able to set font as Bold using RichEdit. Can someone help me to set the hotkey Ctrl+B to call xyz procedure.

Comment: Why is there no bold in this answer?

Comment: @David: Because I didn't notice 'bold' in the question! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: To get Ctrl+B to work as a shortcut I would reccomend using the TActionManager or TActionList for your events (actions). Put shortcut property to Ctrl+B then when you press that on your keyboard your action/event will trigger.